# Formatting pdf using TiJSPDF

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am using [TiJSPDF](https://github.com/AppWerft/TiJSPDF) inside my Titanium application to create a pdf file. My pdf is having a table with 3 columns in it.

The problem I am facing is that the text doesn't fit inside the column width as you can see on here: [image: screenshot]

Could anyone please provide me the styles or the solution code to show the complete text in a column?

Comment: Please add the code of your table

Comment: I agree. Code would be very helpful!